# Use CodeFunction or CodeFunction2 to add parameter for extension methods which require this keyword

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, extension-methods, envdte

I am using Visual Studio Code Automation to generate some custom code and classes.

The following function is meant to generate an extension method

```
private void AddToPocoExtensionMethod(CodeClass2 entityAdapterClass, string name, string modifiedNameCamelCase, List<CodeProperty> properties)
{
    var toPoco = (CodeFunction2)entityAdapterClass.AddFunction("ToPoco", vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionFunction, "I" + name + "Poco", -1, vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic, null);
    toPoco.IsShared = true;
    toPoco.AddParameter(modifiedNameCamelCase + "Entity", "I" + name + "Entity");
}
```

Following code snippet shows the actual method generated.

```
public static IProductPoco ToPoco(IProductEntity productEntity)
{
    IProductPoco productPoco = PocoFactory<IProductPoco>.GetInstance();
    productPoco.ProductId = productEntity.ProductId;
    productPoco.ProductName = productEntity.ProductName;
    productPoco.SupplierId = productEntity.SupplierId;
    productPoco.CategoryId = productEntity.CategoryId;
    productPoco.QuantityPerUnit = productEntity.QuantityPerUnit;
    return productPoco;
}
```

Obviously, it won't work like an extension method because the keyword "this" is missing before the first parameter as in,

```
public static IProductPoco ToPoco(this IProductEntity productEntity)
{
}
```

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szt3ch5t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), the syntax for AddParameter is

```
CodeParameter AddParameter(
string Name,
Object Type,
Object Position
```

)

However, the syntax does not allow for adding "this" key word before the parameter type.

Is there something that I am missing or should I be using some other Api to create a method as an Extension Method? Please share a solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this with the code model.  It does not support adding the necessary syntax for extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an "ExtensionMethod" Extender to the CodeFunction. Check [ExtensionMethodExtender](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp/CodeModel/Extenders/ExtensionMethodExtender.cs) and [ICSExtensionMethodExtender](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp/CodeModel/Interop/ICSExtensionMethodExtender.cs). For example this is how you check if the method is an extension:

```
[ComImport]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("f82170cc-efe8-4f5e-8209-bc2c27b3f54d")]
internal interface ICSExtensionMethodExtender
{
    bool IsExtension { get; }
}

private bool IsExtensionMethod(CodeFunction codeFunction)
{
    ICSExtensionMethodExtender extender = codeFunction.Extender["ExtensionMethod"] as ICSExtensionMethodExtender;
    return codeFunction.IsShared && extender != null && extender.IsExtension;
}
```

This is untested but you can try this:

```
[ComImport]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("f82170cc-efe8-4f5e-8209-bc2c27b3f54d")]
internal interface ICSExtensionMethodExtender 
{
    bool IsExtension { get; }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ICSExtensionMethodExtender))]
public class ExtensionMethodExtender : ICSExtensionMethodExtender
{
    internal static ICSExtensionMethodExtender Create(bool isExtension)
    {
        var result = new ExtensionMethodExtender(isExtension);
        return (ICSExtensionMethodExtender)ComAggregate.CreateAggregatedObject(result);
    }

    private readonly bool _isExtension;

    private ExtensionMethodExtender(bool isExtension)
    {
        _isExtension = isExtension;
    }

    public bool IsExtension
    {
        get { return _isExtension; }
    }
}

private void SetExtension(CodeFunction codeFunction)
{
    ICSExtensionMethodExtender extender = new ExtensionMethodExtender(true);
    codeFunction.Extender["ExtensionMethod"] = extender;
    codeFunction.IsShared = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Can you share some example of how I can use this class or interface to add an extension method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late here. But someone else may need this answer :)

```
yourAddedParameter.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint().Insert("this ");
```